# How to add dynamic slots in vue 3 components?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

In vue 3, say I have a component like this

```
<table>
    <template v-slot:item.hello="{item}">
        {{item.hello}}
    </template>
</table>
```

however, lets say I now have an array of strings like `['hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3']`. How can I write this out, but dynamically, like reading from the array using `v-for` instead of hardcoding it like this:

```
<table>
    <template v-slot:item.hello1="{item}">
        {{item.hello1}}
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item.hello2="{item}">
        {{item.hello2}}
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item.hello3="{item}">
        {{item.hello3}}
    </template>
</table>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to loop through the array and pass the array item like `v-slot:item[arrayItem]="{item}"`:

```js
<table>
    <template v-for="greeting in greetings" v-slot:item[greeting]="{item}">
        {{item[greeting]}}
    </template>

</table>
```